# Wordpress, Redirect to random post from spesific categories

Tags: wordpress, redirect, post, random, categories

```
add_action('template_redirect','random_template');
function random_template() {
       if (get_query_var('random') == 1) {
               $posts = get_posts('category_name="Kategori 3"&post_type=post&orderby=rand&numberposts=1');

        foreach($posts as $post) {
                       $link = get_permalink($post);
               }
               wp_redirect($link,307);
               exit;
       }
}
```

with this piece of code i am retrieving a post from selected category, how can set the category name to a string, its not working when i do this

category_name=$categorynameisblabla

i just solved it by using cat id instead of cat name